# audio duration is NaN

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to get the duration of audio, but the result is `NaN`. the following is what I did, Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```html
<audio class="my-audio"></audio>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    addAudioPlayer();
});

   //dynamically assign id to an audio player
function addAudioPlayer(){

  var index = 0;
 //find class"my-audio-player"
  $(document).find(".my-audio-player").each(function(){
              $(this).attr('id', 'player'+index );
              $(this).append("<source src=\""+mediaFiles[index]+"\" type=\"audio/mp3\" >")
              new AudioPlayer(mediaFiles[index], index); 
               index++;
   });
}

function AudioPlayer(media, index){
   //set objects reference
     this.audio = document.getElementById("player"+ index);  
     this.audio.onloadedmetadata;
     this.audio.play();
     console.log("audio = " + this.audio);
     console.log("audio src = " + this.audio.src);
     console.log("audio dur = " + this.audio.duration);
}
```

Comment: ["If the media data is available but the length is unknown, this value is NaN. "](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration#Value).

Comment: Thanks very much for ur help. I am new to javascript, How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @War10ck Thanks for ur answer. I added the codes, I got "unknown". But I need this.audio.duration to compute other variable.I still dont know how I can get the duration?

Comment: @JenniferHe I'm not sure you can get it if the value isn't returned on the front end.

Comment: @War10ck I tried if I give <audio class="my-audio" id="player0"><source src="..."></audio> directly in the html, then I can get the duration.But if i dynamically add <source> tag, then the duration is NAN. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @JenniferHe - I suspect your problem is actually something different to what has been suggested. Your code seems to me like it won't return the correct src either. The first thing I notice is that you seem to be misusing the onloadmetadata event of the audio element - it's the name of an event handler and as such, you need to set it to refer to a function that will be called when the data is loaded - you're use of it should be a no-op. Next, you need to get the value contained inside the `<src>` element, which is the first childNode of the `<audio>` element. I'll whip up a working demo. :)

Comment: @JenniferHe - My above comment contains an error. Where I've written "`<src>` element", I should have written "`<source>` element"

Comment: @JenniferHe - Also, I've just seen that you wish to create a progress-bar for the playing music. I've altered my code so that it displays a continually updated progress (text) for each track playing. Enoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above, here's a working demo. I've opted to swap the jQuery references for vanilla JS, since that's my preference (and I've not taken the time to familiarize myself with jQuery. One of these years perhaps :) )

You can easily put it back in.

You won't be getting a valid result for the source either, since the `<audio>` element's `src` attribute is empty, what you want is the `src` attribute of the `source` element that's contained within the `<audio>` element.

Another oversight is the scope. Since the `onloadedmetadata` event is a part of the `<audio>` element object, the `this` keyword refers to the `<audio>` element
`this.audio.play()` should be `this.play()`, `this.audio` should be replaced with `this`, `this.audio.src` should be changed to `this.childNodes[0].src` (remember, we want the src attribute of the source element) and finally, `this.audio.duration` should be `this.duration`.
It's also worth pointing out that the `this` on the first line of your `AudioPlayer` refers to the `AudioPlayer` function (object) since you're not assigning the result of new AudioPlayer to anything, this line is essentially doing nothing and can be altered slightly, I've just grabbed a reference to the `<audio>` element and from there set its `onloadmetadata` event handler.

Phew! Got a sore head yet? Scoping in javascript catches everybody out at some point. Many still never quite get the hang of it. ;)

First, here's the complete code:

(**EDIT #2:** updated code so that it displays the progress of each of the playing tracks, updated every 500ms and displayed as a % of the track length - it should be sufficient to give you an idea, I hope)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";

function allByClass(className,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByClassName(className);}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func){for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList); }

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    addAudioPlayer();
}

var mediaFiles = ['audio/voice_welcomeback.mp3', 'audio/Some Chords.mp3'];
var progressIntervalHandle;

function addAudioPlayer()
{
    var index = 0;
    var audioPlayers = allByClass('my-audio-player');
    forEachNode(audioPlayers, audioPlayerEnumCallback);

    progressIntervalHandle = setInterval(updateProgress, 500);

    function audioPlayerEnumCallback(elem, index, elemArray)
    {
        elem.id = 'player'+index;
        elem.innerHTML = "<source src='" + mediaFiles[index] + "' type='audio/mp3'>";
        new AudioPlayer(mediaFiles[index], index);
        index++;
    }
}

function AudioPlayer(media, index)
{
     document.getElementById("player"+ index).onloadedmetadata = function(evt)
     {
        this.play();
        console.log("audio = " + this);
        console.log("audio src = " + this.childNodes[0].src);
        console.log("audio dur = " + this.duration);
    }
}

function updateProgress()
{
    var audioElems = allByClass('my-audio-player');
    var outputMsg = '';

    forEachNode(audioElems, audioElemEnumProgressCallback);
    document.getElementById('progressOutput').innerHTML = outputMsg;

    function audioElemEnumProgressCallback(elem, index, elemAray)
    {
        outputMsg += "Song " + index + ": " + ((100*elem.currentTime) / elem.duration).toFixed(2) + "%" + "<br>";
    }
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <audio class="my-audio-player"></audio>
    <audio class="my-audio-player"></audio>

    Progress:<br>
    <div id='progressOutput'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT #1:** The console output appears pretty much instantaneously upon page-load and the audio files are (both) playing immediately too. I'd have to use a screen-recording application to get even semi-accurate figures, since it all happens so quickly.

**EDIT #3:** Here's the console output. (the line numbers should be on the right-hand side)

```
audioDemo.html:42 audio = [object HTMLAudioElement]
audioDemo.html:43 audio src = file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/enhzflep/audio/voice_welcomeback.mp3
audioDemo.html:44 audio dur = 1.68
audioDemo.html:42 audio = [object HTMLAudioElement]
audioDemo.html:43 audio src = file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/enhzflep/audio/Some%20Chords.mp3
audioDemo.html:44 audio dur = 444.186122
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved the problem by following what u did above :) u r genius!!! I really appreciate ur help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped you solve your problem. Nah, just had a little bit of practise with the language. ;) Any-time. :)

Comment: :) I met a problem again.:(  I have 2 audio player, but the following codes " console.log("audio = " + this);
        console.log("audio src = " + this.childNodes[0].src);
        console.log("audio dur = " + this.duration); " seems that runs only once :(

Comment: It should run once for each audio player that **(a)** is present on the page immediately after it loads and **(b)** has a corresponding item in the `mediaItems` array. I'll add the output I get in the console. Busy for an hour or 2 will look when I return. :)

Comment: Wot?! You just need to check the `audioElement.currentSrc` for the src, and currentTime is set when the metadata is loaded. The problem in OP is just that s/he missed to append the callback to the `onloadedmetadata`.

Comment: @enhzflep Now the two audio players are working. But How can I pause one audio player when another is playing? :)

Comment: @JenniferHe - you just need to call the pause method. So, to pause the first player, it'd be `document.getElementById('player0').pause()` and `document.getElementById('player1').pause()` for the 2nd one. There's an ok-ish reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp - Also, you should read Kaiido's comment and answer - they present a _much_ better way of accessing the source (`.currentSrc`).

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks very muc for ur help. I tried what u said. I can get src for audioElement.currentSrc  :) Is there any way that I can return an audio object after calling onloadedmetadata function ? :)

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks very much. I will try :)

Comment: @JenniferHe `this` will refer to the `audioElement` object in the `onloadedmetadata` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely don't need to dig through your `<audio>` element's childNodes, which is prone to error errors (e.g if you've got multiple `<source>` elements as you're supposed to, or if you set a fallback message into the `<audio>` element.)

In order to get the address of the currently playing media, you need to check for the [AudioElement.currentSrc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentSrc) property.

Your problem of duration returning NaN is just that you tried to get it before the metadata were loaded, because you didn't set anything to the `loadedmetadata` event, and even if you did, the `this` was not referencing to the good object anymore.

```js
var mediaFiles = ["http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp3"];

   //dynamically assign id to an audio player
function addAudioPlayer(){
  var index = 0;
 //find class"my-audio-player"
  $(document).find(".my-audio-player").each(function(){
              $(this).attr('id', 'player'+index );
              $(this).append("<source src=\""+mediaFiles[index]+"\" type=\"audio/mp3\" >")
              new AudioPlayer(mediaFiles[index], index); 
               index++;
   });
}

function AudioPlayer(media, index){
   //set objects reference
     // instead of passing the index, you could simply pass the element as argument
     this.audio = document.getElementById("player"+ index);  
     // you forgot to set onloadedmetadata as a function
     this.audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
       // "this" now refers to the audio element
       this.play();
       snippet.log("audio = " + this);
       // to get the audio src, it is always preferred to get its currentSrc (the one of the choosen media resource)
       snippet.log("audio src = " + this.currentSrc);
       snippet.log("audio dur = " + this.duration);
     }
}

addAudioPlayer();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio class="my-audio-player" controls></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

As *@PaulRoub* pointed out from the linked [MDN Arcticle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration#Value):

> If the media data is available but the length is unknown, this value is NaN. If the media is streamed and has no predefined length, the value is Inf.

To fix this, check for the value of `NaN` and replace it with something more desirable to the user, such as maybe *unknown* or *unknown duration*.

See below for a quick implementation:

```
console.log("audio dur = " 
    + ((this.audio.duration != this.audio.duration) ? "unknown" : this.audio.duration));
```

This is a quick way of searching for the value `NaN`. `this.audio.duration != this.audio.duration` will be true **if and only if** `this.audio.duration` is `NaN`.

Comment: @JenniferHe What other variable would you like to compute?

Comment: in fact, i need a progress bar with current time and remaining time :). I found the problem is timing. once I wait for a while, the duration comes. Do you know how I can solve timing problem?